# FormClosing does not see DataGridView Rows and Columns

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Please, what is wrong with this:
Form2_Closing:

```
Form1.DataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = "323";
```

> Error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the
>   size of the collection. Parameter name: index

DGV on Form1 has 10 Rows and 14 Columns

Comment: Why are you changing the value when the form closes?  My guess is you should do this before its closed.

Comment: Set a breakpoint before that line and find out how many Rows, and how many Cells DataGridView1 says it has.

Comment: I'm changing DGV on Form1 not Form2

Comment: NominSim, it is the only line of code in FormClosing. If I set breakpoint - nothing happens.

Comment: Can you please share the code of how Form1 and Form2 are related ? Is Form2 a _modal child_ of Form1 i.e. spawned via ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner) ?

Comment: You should still be able to set one. Click on the actual FormClocing method line, not on the line of code. Of course it will only be triggered when Form2 closes.

Comment: I load Form2 as ShowDialog(); Form1 is MDI Container. frm01.Text = "323" also does not work.

Comment: Why are you creating an MDI child using ShowDialog() ? That will disable all windows. Why now just Show()?

Comment: Angshuman, it is because i don't want user to do anything on form1 till form2 is opened

Comment: No, you can achieve it by setting the enable property to false and not relying on DialogResult. See my answer below.

Comment: I tried Form2.Show(); instead Form2.ShowDialog();. The same error. Form2 does not see Form1 at all. Form1.Text = "323" also does not work.

Comment: You may notice in the answer that I am using the overloaded Show() method. You are not passing the owner.

Comment: Angshuman, I have any DialogResult nor OK button. I'm just closing Form2 by the x topright button.

Comment: Se answer below. Updated it with _DialogResult.None_. You will get this when you close (X) the child form.

Comment: You may copy-paste the code in the answer and try to run.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12443/discussion-between-angshuman-agarwal-and-bonaca)

Comment: You have conflicting statements.  In one of your comments you say that "frm01.Text = "323"" works.  In a later comment you say "Form1.Text = "323"" works.  Is your form named frm01 or Form1?  Please show more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Winforms Project and add a button & its click handler and a TextBox *[make it accessible, such that the child can set value. I have made it public in the designer for now]* too. Then add the following code on this Form. Additionally, add a new Form (Form2) in the Project.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var child = new Form2();
            child.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(ChildFormClosing);
            this.Enabled = false;
            child.Show(this);
        }

        void ChildFormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            var child = sender as Form2;
            if (child != null)
            {
                if (child.DialogResult == DialogResult.None)
                {
                    // do data grid view manipulation here 
                    // for ex:
                   (child.Owner as Form1).textBox1.Text = "Hi";
                }
            }
            Enabled = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

From your comments it looks like you are trying to create a custom Dialog that will manipulate a particular value within a `DataGridView` on the calling form. I suggest looking at [this](http://www.techlicity.com/blog/dotnet-creating-a-custom-messagebox.html) example of creating a custom message box.

You'll be able to return say the value that you want the `DataGridViewCell` updated to, then set it on your `Form1`.

Comment: Form2 is not a custom dialog, it's a normal form, with DGV and other controls on it.

Comment: You're using it as a dialog though, so the same principles should apply.